# Should the button move if a player leaves the table in the blinds positions?

Tags: rules, blinds, button

A friend told me yesterday in my club when a player leaves the table in the blinds positions, the button stays in the same position in order to maintain blinds order.

My concern is then a player has two consecutive times position.

What is the rule?

Comment: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11039/dealer-and-small-blind-go-bust-how-does-dealer-button-move-in-this-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your freind was generally right, the button should move to the last player whom has posted both blinds. some localities california for example always move the button to the next player and have particular procedures about whom needs to post blinds. this is because players pay time every "time"they have the button.this is a result of stupip bureaucracy the law says they cannot rake apot in poker so they came up eith a way to call rake time.